# Expansion of $S=\frac{{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n}+1}}{(x-1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Expand;

$S=\frac{{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n}+1}}{(x-1)^2}$

See solution, Also I am looking for an advance method if exists.

Answer (score 1):

We can also see that $$S =\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2} $$ $$\implies S(1-x)=\frac{(n+1)x^n-nx^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)[1+x+x^2…x^{n-1}-nx^n]}{x-1}=[1+x+x^2+…x^{n-1}-nx^n]$$ $$S=\frac{1+x+x^2…x^{n-1}-nx^n}{1-x}=[1+x+x^2+…][1+x+x^2+…x^{n-1}-nx^n] = ?$$

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

$S=\frac{{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n}+1}}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{{(n+1)x^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n}+1}-x-x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{(x-1)[(n+1)x^n -1]-(x^{n+1}-x)}{(x-1)^2}=(\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1})^{'}=(x+x^2+x^3+ . . .x^n)^{'}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+ . . .nx^{n-1}$

Comment: Now, you give answers to your own questions ?

Comment: Jean Marie, it is nothing wrong to answer your own question, it is for sharing knowledge as the site proposes!

Comment: Shame on silent down voter

Comment: You should have given the solution inside your question, just after the question itself (not as a answer) "Text of the question. My solution is : ... text of the solution..., I am looking forward for a different solution".

Comment: Sorry I did not know this regulation. But my contribution was not worth of down voting . You could have said this before down voting. I still can change my question if possible. I am just discouraged to go on.

Comment: It wasn't the first time that you answer your own question with a downvoting : (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1953907).